# Error in Dax Studio for a simple LOOKUPVALUE

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am new to PBI and DAX. I am using Dax Studio to explore some functions. I am trying to do a look up value on a simple table. The table is Users and it has 2 columns, Name and ClientID. This is my DAX formula that I have in the Studio editor

```
LOOKUPVALUE(Users[ClientID], [Name], "john smith")
```

When I run it I get this output

[image]

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing it wants a fully qualified column name.

Try this:

```
LOOKUPVALUE(Users[ClientID], Users[Name], "john smith")
```

---

**Edit:**

DAX Studio generally expects table output rather than measure output. You can get around this by turning your value into a table.

Try this:

```
EVALUATE {LOOKUPVALUE(Users[ClientID], Users[Name], "john smith")}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried this and I am getting the same error. When I create a column in PBI desktop and input the formula there it all works fine. I am just trying to figure out how to use DAX Studio. I would prefer not to make a column when I test functions. I was hoping I could use DAX Studio as a playground to test around in